# How to retrieve all datomic created uris / database names?

Tags: datomic

Where does datomic store the uri's / database names ?

I.e. where is Peer.connect() looking ?

In the meantime I'm trying to debug the "web console" to see how the database drop down is populated.

Answer (score 1):

Datomic doesn't store the URI's anywhere, it stores the database names within the storage. The URI is an address that describes both a storage location and a database within it. You can find the databases available within a storage location by using [`getDatabaseNames`](http://docs.datomic.com/javadoc/datomic/Peer.html#getDatabaseNames(java.lang.String)) from Java or [`get-database-names`](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/#datomic.api/get-database-names) in Clojure. `connect` is attempting to connect to a storage location at the URI and a transactor connected to the same database.